# Is it possible to set a variable equal to another variable in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm relatively new to Swift and would like to know if it is possible to set a variable equal to another variable in Swift. I have a dummy counter variable that I would like to set equal to another variable, but it gives me an error. It seems to be possible in the Playground environment, but not in the ViewController.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 10.0
    var count2 = count
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean setting variable equal to another?

Comment: paste your variable declarations and the assignment code so we can provide feedback.

Comment: Are you assigning the variables in the same class?

Comment: if class one is a variable and class two is same variable it should be like this, 
Class 1 myVar = 1  class 2 Class1.myVar = "New variable";

Comment: import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 10.0
    var count2 = count
...etc
Sorry about the formatting.. still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Provided both are of the same type, it is _always_ possible to make a variable "equal" to another. I think it is called "assignment".

Comment: On the other hand, if you want one variable to act as an "alias" of another, so that making changes to either of them results in changes to both... It _is_ possible, provided A) They are reference types (objects of class type), _not_ value type (e.g. structs)., and B) You are changing the properties of the object assigned to the variable, not which object the variable references (the latter will "break the link").

Comment: I think  you can try var count = 10.0
    var count2: Int? {
        return Int(count)
    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I would suggest you to use a `lazy` property which only gets initialized when you access it:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 10.0
    lazy var count2: Int = { self.count }()
    ...
}
```

### Some more information about the syntax and semantics:

- lazy: Explained above
- `{ self.count }`: A closure which is a function without a name and is executed with the parenthesis `()` after the body.

  Like a function it has a return type (`Int`) and in this case Swift infers the `return` so the closure is equivalent to `{ return self.count }`.

For more information see these links about [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) and [lazy properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID257).

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure, if i understand your needs, but likely you can use property observers for  'variables' to force both having the same value

```
struct S {
    var a: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if b != a {
                b = a
            }
        }
    }
    var b: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if a != b {
                a = b
            }
        }
    }
}

var s = S()
s.a = 10
print(s)    // S(a: 10, b: 10)
s.b = 100
print(s)    // S(a: 100, b: 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change it as follows and it did't give me the error msg Instance member count cannot be used in view controller.

```
var count = 10.0
   var count2: Int? {
    return Int(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the type or an initial value during the declaration of the variable inside a class:

```
var count = 10
var count2 : Int
```

And then, in the initializer of the class set them equal:

```
init() {
     count2 = count
}
```